# Creating a list of words does not work with a list of sentences

Tags: python-2.7, list

I am trying to take a list of sentences and split each list into new lists containing the words of each sentence.

```
def create_list_of_words(file_name):

    for word in file_name:
        word_list = word.split()
    return word_list


sentence = ['a frog ate the dog']
x = create_list_of_words(sentence)
print x
```

This is fine as my output is 
['a', 'frog', 'ate', 'the', 'dog']

However, when I try to do a list of sentences it no longer reacts the same.

```
my_list = ['the dog hates you', 'you love the dog', 'a frog ate the dog']

for i in my_list:
    x = create_list_of_words(i)
    print x
```

Now my out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've had few issues at your second script:

1. `i` is `'the dog hates you'` while in the first script the parameter was `['a frog ate the dog']` -> one is string and second is list.
2. `word_list = word.split()` with this line inside the loop you instantiate the `word_list` each iteration, instead use the append function as i wrote in my code sample.
3. When sending string to the function you need to split the string before the word loop.

Try this:

```
def create_list_of_words(str_sentence):
    sentence = str_sentence.split()
    word_list = []
    for word in sentence:
        word_list.append(word)
    return word_list


li_sentence = ['the dog hates you', 'you love the dog', 'a frog ate the dog']
for se in li_sentence:
    x = create_list_of_words(se)
    print x
```

Comment: Yes I see the error now thank you.  In fact I see that the 'for' loop is not necessary because I was using the .split().  sentence = str_sentence.split() is all that is needed in the bottom 'for' loop .

Comment: `word_list = [word for eachList in [subList.split() for subList in my_list] for word in eachList]`

List Comprehension can accomplish this as well.